# Is it possible to use a.bat file to toggle Steam joystick preferences?

Tags: steam, controllers

I have two Steam games that require different configurations in the **Steam/settings/Controller/GENERAL CONTROLLER SETTINGS** page that I would like to somehow be able to change with a script. Here is the location of the settings:

[image]

I'd like to use a .bat file to toggle between the two different configurations. The two setups are as follows:

1 - **Resident Evil 4 UHD** which requires that all joysticks are disabled as I am using [x360ce.exe](https://www.x360ce.com/) to handle my joystick mappings for this game:

[image]

2 - **Prey** which requires that some joysticks are enabled:

[image]

I'd like to toggle between these 2 setups with a .bat file command so that I can add these to startup launchers so that I do not have to manually go to these settings each time I play each game.

I have read that Steam console commands support .bat files but I have no idea which console commands govern these joystick configurations, or how to use a .bat file to add arguments while launching the game. Perhaps there is simply a way to use launch options for each individual game that will use its own joystick preference?

Comment: Steam games have a "Launch Options" setting, where you can set command line options for the game. Maybe it can be done through that dialog?

Comment: yes, that is part of the question.

Comment: As long as the setting for joystick is stored in one of Steam's many config files, yes, this could be done. BATch script may not be the best though as it may need to parse & rebuild at least one file to do so -- in that case PowerShell or WSH's version of JS would be better, especially because there are NodeJS parsers that could be converted. NodeJS or Python would be the best languages though as they've already got text VDF (Valve Data Format, similar to JSON) parsers built.